# Не могу передать путь к файлу

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Пробовал передать значение, но при выборе файла и уже передачи значения , у меня пишет, что не определен. То есть fileDialog.fileUrl неопределен, если написать так console.log(fileDialog.fileUrl). А если я делаю обращение к c++, то значение так указано "". Подскажите, что делать? Qt6.6 . Ниже код:
back.cpp:

```
#include "back.h"
back::back(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
}

void back::changeValue(QString a)
{
    text = a;
    emit valueChanged();
}
```

back.h:

```
#ifndef BACK_H
#define BACK_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

class back : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString value MEMBER text NOTIFY valueChanged)

public:
    explicit back(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE void changeValue(QString a);

signals:
    void valueChanged();

private slots:
    void vc();

private:
    QString text;
};

#endif // BACK_H
```

main.qml:

```
FileDialog{
          id: fileDialog
            nameFilters: ["7zip (*.7z)", "ZIP-архив (*.zip)"]
            currentFolder: StandardPaths.standardLocations(StandardPaths.DesktopLocation)[0]
            onAccepted:
            {
                var filePath = fileDialog.fileUrl;
                if (filePath !== null && filePath !== undefined) {
                    back.changeValue(filePath);
                    console.log(filePath);
                } else {
                    console.log("Пользователь не выбрал файл.");
                }
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение вопроса. Для Qt 6.6.0 и 6.5.0 , ввели новое свойство selectedFile. Разработчики оставили fileUrl, но он возвращает "неопределено". Также и для fileUrls его новый аналог selectedFiles. Надеюсь это поможет.

Comment: Возможно, но тоже без его комментариев не понятно о чем я говорил

Comment: Мои комментарии относились к оформлению  вопроса. То, о чем в них говорилось, касалось устранения возможной путаницы, но не помогало найти ответ. Когда вопрос, который в них был поднят, был решен (не важно, в целом, положительным или отрицательным образом) комментарии стали не нужны, более того - добавляли лишний шум. Поэтому я их удалил, в надежде, что автор вопроса удалит свои.